# convert syntax to swift 3.0 NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

how can I convert my NSFetchedResultsController to swift 3.0, i can't get it to work.... I tried apple's auto conversion but it's not working??

I had this:

```
lazy var fetchedResultsControler: NSFetchedResultsController = {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Mesages")
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "timestamp", ascending: true)]
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "user.id = %@", self.friend!.id!)
    let moc = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
    let frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: moc, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    frc.delegate = self
    return frc
}()
```

automatically converted to this:

```
    lazy var fetchedResultsControler: NSFetchedResultsController = { () -> <<error type>> in
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Mesages")
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "timestamp", ascending: true)]
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "user.id = %@", self.friend!.id!)
    let moc = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
    let frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: moc, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    frc.delegate = self
    return frc
}()
```

but It's not working, it's asking me to put semi colons in random places

Answer (score 2):

It is needed to set up `NSFetchRequestResult` inside brackets <>.

***For swift 3.0:***

```
lazy var fetchedResultsControler: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult> = {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Mesages")
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "timestamp", ascending: true)]
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "user.id = %@", self.friend!.id!)
    let moc = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
    let frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: moc, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    frc.delegate = self
    return frc
}()
```